# Assign @ to a separate object for ease of namespacing

Tags: javascript, namespaces, coffeescript

In coffeescript you can assign an object or class to the global namespace by prepending the definition with the `@` symbol.

e.g.

```
class @Dog #This is now available via window.Dog due to the @
   constructor : () ->
```

But is there someway to assign the `@` symbol to another object, instead of window?

When I tried `@ = {}`, I got `error: unexpected =`

This would allow you to always define your objects to be a namespace, but change your mind about what namespace that is at a later time.  It allows you to avoid exporting on a case by case basis.  You can set @ to global while testing and then set it to an alternate namespace when deployed.

If there is a better approach, or an alternate way to achieve a similar goal that would be great too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** assign something to `this`, `this` is the scope variable.

I *guess* you could make some function to set the namespace:

```
@scope = do ( -> return @ ) #change `@` at the end to your namespace
```

Then you would do:

```
class @scope.Dog
   constructor: () ->
      ...
```

Which parses to:

```
this.scope = (function() {
  return this;
})();

this.scope.Dog = (function() {

  function Dog() {
      ...
  }

  return Dog;

})();
```

Comment: I like this approach thank you.  I ended up defining a simple object `scope = @` at the top of the code and from then on everything in that document is defined `scope.Dog`.  You can easily alter the namespace at anytime for all objects _and_ any readers of your code can easily see what is going on.

Was there an advantage to defining `@scope` as a function (as opposed to an object) that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the `this` at the top level, but you can [call a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) with a different `this` scope:

```
(->
  class @Dog
    talk: -> console.log 'woof!'
  class @Cat
    talk: -> console.log 'meow'
).call animals = {}

# Now the animals "namespace" has a Cat and a Dog properties.
(new scope.Cat).talk()
```

The example doesn't make too much sense, as it could be written as `animals = {}; class animals.Cat` and avoid the need for that extra nesting level, but if you're looking for changing the `this` dynamically at some point, it's nice to know about the existence of `Function#call` :)

Answer (score 0):

Using @ as reference to *window* object may be misleading and can lead to errors (when context changes). Better is to declare some custom namespace.

You put a line in the first script you're loading:

```
window.myns ?= {}
```

...and later use it instead of @ like:

```
class myns.Dog
```

Just to be safe you add the namespace declaration line on top of each file in which you'll be reffering to it. It's not mandatory though. Just be sure scripts are loaded in proper order.